# Встреча запятой и тире

Tags: пунктуация

Ув. филологи! Следует ли ставить запятую или достаточно только тире?

В жизни, как в такси, – счетчик щелкает, стоишь ты или продолжаешь движение.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагается в качестве одного из вариантов: "В жизни как в такси – счетчик щелкает, стоишь ты или продолжаешь движение".
Второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого, при этом возможна постановка тире или двоеточия. Тире ставится при отсутствии предупредительной паузы.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) Похожие по структуре предложения обычно оформляются следующим образом: "В жизни, как в плохой пьесе, всегда оказываются лишние персонажи". "В жизни, как в море, нередко случаются внезапные бури, смущающие ее будничный покой". Однако в этих примерах нет деления предложения на две части. Здесь обычный сравнительный оборот.

2) Похожий двухчастный вариант: "В жизни, как в театре. Сильные сидят в первом ряду, а умные играют для них роли в спектакле".

3) Еще  похожие варианты с разным оформлением: В жизни, как в сказке – чем дальше, тем страшнее. В жизни как в сказке, чем дальше, тем страшнее. В жизни всё как в сказке – чем дальше, тем страшнее.

4) Выбираем наиболее подходящий: В жизни (всё) как в сказке – чем дальше, тем страшнее.
Это БСП, но следует определить вид простого предложения. Можно считать, что предложение неполное (пропущено подлежащее). Но более вероятен вариант безличного предложения с пропущенной связкой и именной частью,  выраженной сравнительным оборотом. Для сравнения: Там красиво/там было красиво. Там как в сказке/там было как в сказке.

5) Таким же образом оформляем заданное предложение: "В жизни как в такси – счетчик щелкает, стоишь ты или продолжаешь движение".

Answer (score 4):

***В жизни как в такси: счетчик щелкает, стоишь ты или продолжаешь движение.***

Предложение бессоюзное, вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой, поэтому ставим двоеточие.

Выражение "как в такси" запятой не отделяем, так как это сказуемое.

Comment: Скажите, как вы определяете вид первого предложения?

Comment: Безличное неполное. Оборот примыкает к отсутствующему здесь сказуемому (например, к сказуемому СЛУЧАЕТСЯ), поэтому запятую не ставим.

Comment: Вряд ли можно считать предложение неполным, так как неполное предложение восстанавливается из контекста. Вообще говоря, любые подстановки изменяют вид конструкции: мы имеем похожий смысл, но уже предложение-синоним с другой структурой. Лучше считать, что в безличном предложении пропущена отвлеченная связка "быть".