# "Жизнь, как сказка – чем дальше, тем страшнее" – каким правилом руководствоваться при постановке тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Жизнь, как сказка - чем дальше, тем страшнее.**

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Если правильно, то меня интересует постановка тире. Я всегда стараюсь проверять постановку -/: вспомогательными словами: *"это", "а/но", "если, то", "поэтому", "вот", "будто/словно"* - для постановки тире, а *"потому что", "что", "а именно"* - для двоеточия. В принципе, работает, но порой встречаются вот такие предложения, где и *"поэтому"* можно вставить и *"потому что"* к месту. В общем, каким правилом мне здесь руководствоваться?

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39209/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5

Comment: Еще одно интересное обсуждение здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430811/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5/430831#430831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь возможно большое число вариантов.

1. Рассмотрим первую часть (Жизнь () как сказка).

1.1. Жизнь как сказка. Объяснение: *жизнь* – подлежащее, *как сказка* – сказуемое, *как* выступает в роли связки, поэтому тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится.

1.2. Жизнь – как сказка. Объяснение: как (1.1), но тире допустимо, если это связано с желанием подчеркнуть оттенок сравнения, содержащийся в сказуемом. Например: *Тишина – как льдинка, ее сломаешь даже шепотом (Леонов).*

1.3. Жизнь, как сказка. Объяснение: *как сказка* – сравнительный оборот. Если в (1.1) и (1.2) мы хотели сказать, что жизнь подобна сказке, то здесь смысл иной: "жизнь, подобная сказке" (сказуемого нет).

2. Рассмотрим вторую часть (Чем дальше () тем страшнее).

2.1. Чем дальше, тем страшнее. Объяснение: двойной союз *чем...тем*, обычно ставится запятая перед *тем*.

2.2. Чем дальше – тем страшнее. Объяснение: авторское интонационное тире. Примеры: *Но и рисунки не помогли, и чем дальше― тем путанее и непонятнее становилось заявление поэта.* [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)].  *Чем дальше ― тем страшнее, за Перекопом ― мертвые пески».* [А. Н. Толстой. Петр Первый. Книга первая (1930)]

3. Рассмотрим сочетание первой и второй части.

3.1. *Первая часть*: *вторая часть* (жизнь подобна сказке, потому что ...)

3.2. *Первая часть* – *вторая часть* (жизнь подобна сказке, поэтому ...)

Таким образом, вы должны решить, какой именно смысл вы вкладываете в это предложение.

Мой вариант:

**Жизнь – как сказка: чем дальше – тем страшнее.**

(Наша жизнь подобна сказке, потому что в ней, как и в сказке, чем дальше, тем страшнее становится). Тире как описано в 1.2 и 2.2. Симметричность тире украшает предложение.

Comment: Лаконичные рассуждения, по-другому не скажешь. Спасибо.